# Is there a way to assign shift key to a mouse button?

Tags: shortcut, 3d-mouse

I have a Spacemouse and in Blender for Mac, the Spacemouse settings do not work, so if I need to assign specific buttons, I need to do it via Blender. I would like to use one of the keys as a shift key.

Comment: Sounds like you have the basic 3D mouse - rotation/tilt with a button on each side. Blender maps NDOF buttons to operators, as in an NDOF button works more like an E key not a shift key. I expect you want to use something like [DoubleCommand](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/12004/doublecommand) or [Karabiner](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25141/karabiner)

Answer (score 1):

I think blender maps operators to keys and not keys to operators, so you probably have to remap every operator that uses the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

In user preferences->input ,  you can set the input event to a NDOF device.

[image]

Comment: Yes, additionally you can use the search function on top set to "Key-Binding" to search for any entry that uses Shift so you can manually change it to any desired NDOF button

Comment: That would be quite cumbersome and probably would still not work for selecting multiple objects, faces, etc. When hovering over the shift in an area similar to your snippet, i see the code for using the shift modifier - "KeyMapItem.shift", so I was hoping to use that code as the identifier or operator and map it

Comment: is it possible to say change one operator , export the keymap config , inspect the file and replace every occurrence of shift key with the key code of your 3d mouse? the [exported key configuration](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i09MP.png) is in plain text and a simple find and replace could work , although it would take some trials and errors and lot of patience..